# How does a php script on a contact form access the user's email?

Tags: php, forms, email

This tutorial teaches you how to create a contact form for a website using php script: http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/email.html

But how does this work? How does the script access the user's email account to send an email? How does such a form work without a server? (For example if I put my website on github pages which only handles static pages, how does this php script work?)

Comment: `if i put my website on github pages which only handles static pages, how does this php script work` it won't.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? what would you have to do to get this to work?

Comment: I agree with @Cthulhu, there's no way to make the server do something if the server does only throw HTML pages out. You need some programming language (PHP in your tutorial) to process your code, it has to be installed in the server and accessible to you. It will run your code, decide what to do and do it (by the way to actually send the mail you will need the proper PHP modules available. Because it is the _server_ who sends the mail, not the user's client)

Comment: If you have no serverside intelligence capacity, just use your user's tools. Which means stuck with the `mailto` scheme (as the tutorial's first examples show). Then the _user's computer_ will send the email (with the drawbacks the tutorial points out)

Comment: maybe I'll make this an answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's no way to make the server do something if the server does only throw HTML pages out.

You need some programming language (PHP in your tutorial) to process your code, it has to be installed in the server and accessible to you. It will run your code, decide what to do and do it (by the way to actually send the mail you will need the proper PHP modules available). In this case the script will **not** use the user's email account to send the mail: it is the *server* who sends the mail, not the user's client. You will receive an email from your server, so watch out to ask the user for his email, otherwise you will not be able to get it in any way.

If you have no serverside intelligence capacity, just use your user's tools. Which means stuck with the `mailto` scheme (as the tutorial's first examples show). Then the *user's computer* will send the email (with the drawbacks the tutorial points out)

Answer (score 0):

It uses the `mailto:` [URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme) which is opened by your mail client just like `skype:` scheme is bounded to your Skype client.